# Preventing a marginpar from falling off the page

Tags: marginpar

I sometimes put longer texts in a `\marginpar{...}`-command and if the text where the `\marginpar{...}`-command is located is at the end of a page the text falls off the page instead of being placed on the next page or moves up to line up with the regular text block:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}
\pagebreak
\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent this from happening besides of putting the `\marginpar{...}` elsewhere in the text?

Comment: Try with `\marginpar{\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}`.

Comment: @Bernard that works, if you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be any vertical placement key for the placement of marginboxes in one of the dedicated packages. As a workaround, you can put its contents in a `\parbox` using one of these keys:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\color{blue}
\lipsum[1-3]
\marginpar{\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{\color{red}\lipsum[11]}}

\color{black}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class provides several means of placing text in the margin.

`\marginpar` Text put in the margin level with where the macro is called but vertical space is applied between sequential notes if they would overlap.

`\sidepar` Text put in the margin level where the macro is called but does not float like `\marginpar` so texts may overlap.

`\sidebar` Like `\marginpar` but the text starts near the top of the page and may continue onto later pages if it is too long for the current page. Multiple `\sidebar` are set one after the other.

Perhaps you should consider using `\sidebar` instead of `\marginpar`.